# JAVA Paho mqtt - publish to wildcard

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

how can I publish to a wildcard with Paho mqtt?

I get the following log when trying to publish to `/client/#`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A client can publish a payload to a single topic only, you can't use wildcards for topics while publishing.

You can use wildcards(#+) only for subscribing to the topics.

Resources:

[http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/understanding-mqtt-topics](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/understanding-mqtt-topics/)

[Publish multiple topics in one message MQTT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476930/publish-multiple-topics-in-one-message-mqtt)

Comment: Note that this is also covered in the [mqtt spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc385349267) "The Topic Name in the PUBLISH packet MUST NOT contain wildcard characters [MQTT-3.3.2-2]." (v3.1.1 and v5 have the same statement).